# having issue walking types with reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

So, attempting to walk types looking for those classes with an interface.

Methods:

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
foreach(...)
var types=assembly.GetTypes();
```

Exception:

{"Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information."}

Content of LoaderExceptions:
{"Method 'Do' in type 'namespaceinfo.ImportR' from assembly 'namespaceInfo.Importer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.":"nameSpaceInfo.ImportR"}

Info discovered so far on SO --

- .Net loads in types / assemblies on demand.  Perhaps a dependency hasn't been loaded yet.
- ... that's about it for now.

After spending several hours on this, I'm starting to think that decorating classes with attributes and then walking them afterwards for certain reasons could be a bad idea in some situations.  Clearly other services do this successfully.  What am I missing?  Is there a smart implementation in something like Fluent that I should take a look at?

---

The answer so far is do not walk the types in one particular assembly.  ie. filter it out

Comment: That means you're loading an invalid assembly.  With valid assemblies, your code is a standard pattern.

Comment: @SLaks: I figured... but it executes just fine.  So it must be valid.  Nothing fancy.  Just an abstract method in a base class that gets overrided in the parent to this leaf.  Have tried also implementing in this leaf class as well, but still getting this issue.

Comment: What if you try using that class / method?

Comment: that's what I mean.  That class / method works fine.  Reflection is the thing that dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to load implementations of a specific interface at runtime.  Presumably to create instances and use them within your application.  If so then instead of hand rolling this I would suggest using a framework like MEF which is designed to do exactly this.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291628.aspx

Comment: Took a look at the link.  Yes and no.  Decoupling / composing is used.  Not sure that MEF is the best way forward.  I could try it out though.  Question 1. will an exported type also export class attributes?  Question 2. under MEF, can we Import all exported types that implement an interface nievely, without knowing that they're there in advance?

Answer (score 2):

I would dig into the code inside of [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/) or another Dependency Injection container, personally.

Comment: looks promising.  FOund this.  http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2008/10/18/using-structuremap-2-5-to-scan-all-assemblies-in-a-folder/  I wonder what .LookForRegistries() looks like.